# How do I start same Activity with different text when click two different buttons?

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, assets, android-studio-3.0

I'm building an app.When I click a button it will start an activity(eg.activity_sub) with text "Hello world",and when click on another button it will start the same activity but different text view "hi buddy".
I don't put my button yet because I don't know how to continue.
I'm using android studio.

Here's my java code that gets txtfile from assets.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("assetstext.txt");
        int size = is.available();
        // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        // Convert the buffer into a string.
        String text = new String(buffer);
        // Finally stick the string into the text view.
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.assetstext);
        tv.setText(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Should never happen!
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code above, I understand that the text on the buttons will be read from external file(s)? Or, the text describes what you are trying to accomplish, and you're not sure how?

Comment: Why do you want to start the same activity again? isnt easier to change the textview text when y click the button?.

Comment: Yes,if I dont start same activity then I have to create many activities.because I want to build song lyric app.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the desired text when calling your second activity, as an extra in the calling intent.

```
Intent starterIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.class.this,SecondActivity.class)
starterIntent.putExtra("text_key", "<your text>");
```

"text_key" is the look up key that will let you retrieve the text in the next activity. Each button should set a different value for <"your text"> of course.

Then on the second activity you retrieve the text like this:

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("text_key");
```

Look that Im using the exact key that you used on the first activity (`text_key`) otherwise you wont find the text.

Finally set the text.

Comment: No prob! would you mind accepting the answer if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the text as putextra while launching activity and then in onCreate of Activity getString and display to text view on the basis of your filteration.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what do you want to achieve, do you want two textviews or same textview and two different text?

Nevertheless, I am going to answer for both the condition.

If you want to have multiple textviews then use the setVisibilty method to view or hide the other textview as :

```
// here btn is your button and txtview1 and txtview2 are your textviews 
// objects respectively.
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
             txtView1.setVisibility(View.Gone);
             txtView2.setText("hi buddy!");
         }
  });
```

Or else you can simply override the String in the textview which is much simpler. Just like you did with the previous textview.